# How to migrate SSE chat node express to node hapi

Tags: node.js, express, chat, server-sent-events, hapi

I was testing a SSE node express chat in localhost.It was working perfectly. I was including a chat_server in a demo with hapijs as modular server...and it complain about the express syntax. How can I migrate the code to the right syntax in hapijs?

I am trying to solve changing writeHead and write methods because it's complaing about and adding stream package after searching answers in internet.

```
/*
 * Request handlers
*/
 function handleGetChat(req, res)  {
   console.log('handleGetChat received.');
  // res(chatStream).code(200).type('text/event-stream').header('Connection', 'keep-alive').header('Cache-Control','no-cache');                
//   chatStream.write('\n');
   (function(clientId) {
     clients[clientId] = res;
     clientNames[clientId] = req.params.name;
     console.log('name {$req.params.name}');
     req.on("close", () => {
     delete clients[clientId];
     actUserName = "";

      sendText(clientNames[clientId] + " disconnected!", false);
      delete clientNames[clientId];
     });
   })(++clientId);

   sendText(req.params.name + " connected!", false);
   let allMates = "";
   for (cliId in clientNames) {
   allMates += `${clientNames[cliId]}`;
     if (cliId < clientId) allMates += " ";
   }
   sendText(`logged in [${allMates}]`, false);
 }

let sendText = (text, showUserName = true) => {
  for (clientId in clients) {

 allMates += `${clientNames[cliId]}`;
    if (cliId < clientId) allMates += " ";
   }
```

sendText(`logged in [${allMates}]`, false);
 }

```
let sendText = (text, showUserName = true) => {
  for (clientId in clients) {
   let data = "";
   let date = new Date();
   let timestamp = `[${date.getHours()}:${date.getMinutes()}]`;
    if (showUserName) {
     data = `data: ${timestamp} <${actUserName}> ${text}\n\n`;
    } else {
      data = `data: ${timestamp} ${text}\n\n`;
    }
   //chatStream.push('data: ' + "\n\n");
  }
};

function handleWriteChat(req, res) {
  actUserName = req.body.name;
  sendText(req.body.text);
  res.json({ success: true });
}
```

The commented lines in the code above are the lines with syntax error in hapi. I was already changing the originals write and writeHead with chatstream.